# Where to download JDK 1.6 for OS X?

Tags: macos, java, jdk

Currently I use a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.6.7. Where to download JDK 1.6 for OS X?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x its already on your mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should already be on your MBP, but if not, try here:

[Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 4](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1360)

To see if it's installed on your machine, run: /Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences

Comment: that is NOT the jdk...

Comment: Right, it's the JRE, but that's what the original poster was asking for.

Comment: he mentioned " JDK 1.6 for OS X" explicitly

Comment: But he wanted the JRE

Comment: If you are actually looking for the JDK and not just the JRE, you can install it with brew: `brew cask install java6`

Answer (score 2):

You can download it directly from Apple at: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Answer (score 0):

We can download JDK when we create a project using IntelliJ.
However, JDK 1.6 is not on the list anymore.
You can open your terminal and install it with Homebrew.

```
brew install java6
```

After installing it successfully, you can create a new project, click "ADD JDK" on "Project SDK" box and choose the place you install Java.